# Access a class in a different folder

Tags: java

In my main package I have two classes and a folder with more classes in it. One of the outer classes is a singleton class that I need access to from a bunch of the other classes (which are inside of the subfolder). I can access the singleton from classes on the same level as it no problem but when in one of the subclasses it will not let me access it as the others can. How do I resolve this issue? Just incase here is a layout:

```
com.blah
    [Connect]
        Ftp.java    //I want to be able to say AppConfig.getInstance().blah() in this class
    App.java        //I can say AppConfig.getInstance().blah() in here just fine
    AppConfig.java
```

**EDIT** This is the top of the AppConfig Singleton class:

```
class AppConfig {

    private static AppConfig config = new AppConfig();

    private AppConfig(){}

    public static AppConfig getInstance(){
        return config;
    }

    static Properties prop = new Properties();
...
```

**EDIT** Realized that i needed public infront of AppConfig class declaration. Thanks for the tips guys.

Comment: You can import it as long as it's package visible, but why not just pass the appconfig instance in as a constructor argument when app.blah builds the ftp instance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Import it into your `Ftp` class.

```
import com.blah.AppConfig;
```

(Make sure that `Ftp` is a `public` class when you do this as well.)

You don't have to import classes that are in the same folder, because they're considered to be in the same package.  Anything that is outside of the package you're currently in has to be imported.

Comment: That's what I originally thought, but for some reason it won't allow me to. For your sake I updated op with the top of the AppConfig class to give you a better understanding of whats going on

Answer (score 0):

Ftp.java must be a public class if its singleton so that it will be accessible everywhere

And if its public then there should be no problem accessing it outside just import it in those classes where you want that

```
import com.blah.AppConfig;
```